# Typescript assigning a variable's value through logical operator uses only latter type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

given the following types

```
enum Modes {
  error,
  warning
}

type Notification = {
  title: string;
  text: string;
};

type CustomNotification = Notification & { mode: Modes };

interface Options {
  defaultNotification: Notification;
  customNotification?: CustomNotification;
}
```

I want to assign a variable to `customNotification` if available, otherwise to `defaultNotification`, hence I use the logical OR operator in assignment, as:

```
const notification = customNotification || notificationDefault;
```

then I want to conditionally execute logic depending on the value of `mode` if available.

```
if (notification.mode && notification.mode !== Modes.error) { /** code here */ }
```

However, `notification` is only assigned to type `Notification` rather than `CustomNotification | Notification`, thus typescript throws an error when trying to read `notification.mode` value `Property 'mode' does not exist on type 'Notification'.`

I have even tried to explicitly assign `notification` type to `CustomNotification | Notification` but that did not work.

I don't see why this isn't working, and I wonder if there's a workaround other than refactoring my code to use two variables instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `mode` is a field which does not exists in one member of `Notification | CustomNotification` union. Checking `mode` field for object being `Notification` is operation not allowed, as it has no such field. Below my propositions how to deal with your problem.

### Solution one - type unification with default mode

I would consider instead of having dual types here, have one type, and introduce inside `Modes` some neutral element lets say - `default`, when we do so all types problem go away, and we don't need to do any type assertions or guards. Consider:

```
enum Modes {
  error,
  warning,
  default, // neutral value
}

type Notification = {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  mode: Modes;
};

interface Options {
  defaultNotification: Notification;
  customNotification?: Notification;
}

// getting active notification helper
const getNotification = (options: Options): Notification => {
    return options.customNotification ?? options.defaultNotification;
}

// using
const notification = getNotification(options);
if (notification.mode !== Modes.error) { /** code here */ }
```

The only thing we need to do is set `defaultNotification` to an object with `mode` equal `Modes.defalut`.

### Solution two - mode as explicit undefined field

Eventually if you want to keep `Modes` in current shape, we can introduce `mode` field as an `undefined` field in `defaultNotification`. Consider following:

```
type BaseNotification = {
  title: string;
  text: string;
};

type DefNotification = BaseNotification & { mode?: undefined } // pay attention here
type CustomNotification = BaseNotification & { mode: Modes }

type Notification = DefNotification | CustomNotification;

interface Options {
  defaultNotification: DefNotification;
  customNotification?: CustomNotification;
}

const getNotification = (options: Options): Notification => {
    return options.customNotification ?? options.defaultNotification;
}
```

The main point here is `{ mode?: undefined }`, we say that our `DefNotification` has `mode` field but the only possible value for it is `undefined`.